# fetch_array() not preserving ORDER BY from query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this is my code:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

//TESTING CONNECT
include 'connect.php';
$mysqli = connectDB();
getWells(2, $mysqli);

function getWells($company,$mysqli){
//include 'connect.php';
define("MAX_TOP", 96);//96 INCHES == 8 FEET
define("BARRELS_PER_INCH", 1.67);

//$company = $_GET['company'];
//$mysqli = connectDB();

$count = 0;
$sql = "SELECT wells.id, name, top, bottom, last_pulled, bbl_per_hour
        FROM wells, history
        WHERE company_id ='$company'
        AND wells.id = well_id
        AND last_record = 1;";

if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $well_name = $row['name'];
        $well_id = $row['id'];
        $last_bottom = $row['bottom'];
        $last_pulled = $row['last_pulled'];
        $bbl = $row['bbl_per_hour'];

        $projected_fill = MAX_TOP - $last_bottom;
        $projected_barrels = $projected_fill * BARRELS_PER_INCH;
        $time_to_fill = $projected_barrels/$bbl; 
        $exploded_time = explode('.', $time_to_fill);
        $hours = $exploded_time[0];                     
        $frac_hours = '.'.$exploded_time[1];
        $minutes = floor($frac_hours*60);
        $projected = strtotime($last_pulled." +".$hours." hours"." +".$minutes." minutes");            
        $projected_datetime = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s",$projected);    

        $insert = "INSERT INTO temp_wells (well_id,well_name,last_pull,hrs_to_fill)
                   VALUES ('$well_id','$well_name','$last_pulled','$projected_datetime');";
        if(!$result2 = $mysqli->query($insert)){
            return "There was a problem inserting data into databse. Contact Larsoon Computer Services. - GetWells.php, Line 57 ".$mysqli->error;
        }
        else{
            $get_temp = "SELECT * FROM temp_wells
                         ORDER BY hrs_to_fill ASC;";
            if(!$result3 = $mysqli->query($get_temp)){
                return "There was a problem retrieving data. Contact Larson Computer Services. - GetWells.php, Line 63 ".$mysqli->error;
            }
            else{
                //echo var_dump($result3);
                while ($row1 = $result3->fetch_array()) {
                    $o_well_id = $row1['well_id'];
                    $o_well_name = $row1['well_name'];
                    $o_pull_date = $row1['hrs_to_fill'];

                    //TESTING DATA OUTPUT
                    echo $o_well_id;
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo $o_well_name;
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo $o_pull_date;
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<br>';

                    //CREATE THE COUNTDOWN   
                    $date = date('U',  strtotime($o_pull_date));
                    $difference = $date - date('U');
                    $diff_days = floor($difference/(24*60*60));
                    $diff_hours = floor($difference % (24 * 60 * 60) / 3600);
                    $diff_min = floor(($difference % (24 * 60 * 60) % 3600)/60);
                    $diff_secs = floor((($difference % (24 * 60 * 60) % 3600)%60)/1);

                    if($diff_days <= 0){
                        $countdown =  "$diff_hours hrs $diff_min min";
                    }
                    else{
                        $countdown =  "$diff_days days $diff_hours hrs $diff_min min";
                    }
                    if($count == 0) {
                        $data_str = $o_well_id.'|'.$o_well_name.'|'.$countdown;
                        $count++;
                    }
                    else {
                        $data_str = $data_str.'|'.$o_well_id.'|'.$o_well_name.'|'.$countdown;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $truncate = "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_wells;";
        if(!$result4 = $mysqli->query($truncate)){
            return "There was a problem truncating table. Contact Larson Computer Services. ".$mysqli->error;
        }
    }
}//END OF IF
if($data_str == null && $data_str == ""){
    $data_str = 0;
}
return $data_str;
}

?>
```

Produces:

```
1
ATESTWELL
2012-08-17 14:55:37 

3
HAMLET 1-11H
2012-08-17 17:40:00

4
HAMLET 2-11H
2012-08-17 18:47:14

8
DANIEL 1-33H
2012-08-17 13:15:39

6
DANIEL 21-33H
2012-08-19 13:47:16

9
FAVER 1-29H
2012-08-17 14:31:00
```

the table looks like:

```
well_id     int(11)

well_name   varchar(50)

last_pull   datetime

hrs_to_fill datetime
```

Which is not ordered by datetime field like it should be. Running the query on PHPMyadmin works fine, but this code is not... Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: Can you post the design view of the table that you are querying? what is the data type of the hrs_to_fill ?

Comment: Most likely you execute a code different from the one you posted. Make sure PHP file you execute is the one you want. Another option is the page being cached by the browser.

Comment: @LouieV, based on your code you truncate temp_wells table EACH time after running insert. How come you have got more than one row in it?

Comment: @Andy because of the nature of the data I need to calculate $projected_datetime->insert to temp-> fetch with an order by. Also before I truncate I'm doing the fetch, but is not fetching ordered

Comment: It's a good thing that you're using `mysqli`, but you're using it wrong. **NEVER** put strings in your SQL directly. **ALWAYS** use `?` placeholders and bind the values afterwards. [Proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is essential.

Comment: @hookman I know. if($result = $mysqli->query($query)) returns a 1 on success

Comment: @tadman I have not sanitized because this is going to run on a WAMP used by a 50yr old

Comment: @Andy I guess initially I did not understood what you meant. But I got it. The initial while wraps all the code instead of wrapping until I do the entry on temp_wells, causing it to fetch->calculate->insert->fetch in order->output->truncate. Thanks Andy... I'm dumb :)

Comment: What if `$company` is `O'Crockety's Bucket Co.`? Not sanitizing is not to prevent attackers, it's to prevent bugs. There's **no** excuse for being sloppy about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is actually ordered; if you look closely, you will see that for each well it sorts based on date/time. The reason is that you have two loops, the inner loop gets run three times, one for each well.

You may have to move the inner loop after the outer loop, so that you populate the `temp_wells` table in the first loop and query it in the second.

Comment: Correct ! for each `well`, `hrs_to_fill` is ordered (see HAMLET and DANIEL)

Comment: I had moved some code from one loop to the other a few times and ended up mixing the code. Anyways thank you all for your input